# Webcam capture - timeout when requesting image

Tags: java, image, webcam, image-recognition, webcam-capture

I'm using [webcam capture](https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture) to get a webcam image in Java via the following code:

```
Webcam webcam = Webcam.getWebcamByName("VF0415 Live! Cam Vid. IM Ultra 1");  // USB webcam
webcam.open();
BufferedImage image = webcam.getImage();
ImageIO.write(image, "JPG", new File("test.jpg"));
```

Unfortunately, I get a timeout with the following error:

```
[main] INFO com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam - WebcamDefaultDriver capture driver will be used
[atomic-processor-1] INFO com.github.sarxos.webcam.ds.cgt.WebcamOpenTask - Opening webcam VF0415 Live! Cam Vid. IM Ultra 1
[frames-refresher-[1]] ERROR com.github.sarxos.webcam.ds.buildin.WebcamDefaultDevice - Timeout when requesting image!
[shutdown-hook-1] INFO com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamShutdownHook - Automatic VF0415 Live! Cam Vid. IM Ultra 1 deallocation
[shutdown-hook-1] INFO com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam - Disposing webcam VF0415 Live! Cam Vid. IM Ultra 1
[frames-refresher-[1]] ERROR com.github.sarxos.webcam.ds.buildin.WebcamDefaultDevice - Timeout when requesting image!
```

I've looked through related issues on GitHub, and I've tried [keeping my USB power on](https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture/issues/429) and [intercepting the OS signals](https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture/issues/409), but the error messages remain the same, giving me an essentially black image, as shown here:

[image: an essentially black image]

Is there anything else I can try to fix this?

Comment: Sounds like an issue with *their* code, not *yours*, so this is the wrong place to ask.